# libgsasl повтор шага

Tags: c++, c, auth, lib, gnu

я пытаюсь прикрутить к серверу расширенную SASL-аутентификацию. Если допустим наступает этап проверки пары логин:пароль и мне надо проверить список пар, то что делать. Как типо сделать шаг из одного и того же состояния несколько раз для проверки, а также как понять на каком шаге надо это делать.